# Create a button for a user to create a screenshot

Tags: javascript, css, html, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am hoping someone may have a solution for a situation I am in. I have created an online web map tool that leverages javascript, html5, jquery, and CSS to distribute information such as zoning and streets to users. The problem I have run into is getting the page to print once the user finds what they are looking for. I have tried:

1. Using CSS to create a print setup that works across multiple browsers but it does not work correctly and the mapDiv does not print correctly as it does not center on the map but instead focuses on only a certaing portion of the Did.
2. Using html2canvas to print the canvas, but it will not print the mapDiv, but will print everything else.
3. Using fireshot api for creating the screenshot, but it will only work in Friefox from what I have seen.
4. Using the ESRI print javascript api tool, but it does not generate the desired result either.

This being said, ultimately what I would like to create is a button which will screen capture what the user sees and allow them to save it to their own disk and the print. I know javascript and html does not natively have this functionality because of potential security risks and the like, but I was hoping someone here may have found a plugin which works to create a screen capture. I am okay processing this on my server if needed, but in essence I need a way of doing a Alt+PrtScr without having the user do this themselves so they capture what they are seeing.

Any and all thoughts are welcome. Also explanation of how to leverage any plugins would be helpful as well as I am a bit of a rookie at this aspect of coding and want to make sure I enable this tool properly. Thanks!